# InnerHTML changes old variables

Tags: javascript, html-table, refresh, innerhtml

I'm doing a function that creates a table in JS.
I create a variable **`table_row`** fill it and then add **`table_layout.appendChild(table_row);`** it to the **`table_layout`** element.
Next, I clean it **`table_row`** through **`innerHTML=''`**, but when cleaning, the variable that I **ALREADY** added to the element **`table_layout`** **is also cleared**.

---

Why is this happening?
Should the added element be cleared?
How can this be avoided?
Look at the **[CODE](https://codepen.io/magistr4815/pen/LzqgKp)**.

```js
var columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
var rows = 5;

function Table() {
  var table_layout = document.createElement("table");
  var table_row = document.createElement("tr");

  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    // main row
    table_row.innerHTML += "<th>" + columns[i] + "</th>";
  }

  table_layout.appendChild(table_row); //add in table element

  // table_row.innerHTML = ""; //If you uncomment this line, then we get an empty output!
  
  //refresh table_row html, that would generate a new line
  //But when cleaning. Cleared in the previously added item in table_layout .... how??

  
  
  //    for (var j = 0; i < columns.length; j++) {
  //      table_main_row.innerHTML += '<td></td>';
  //     }

  //    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  //     table_layout.appendChild(table_row);
  //    }

  return table_layout;
}

var div = document.getElementById("qqq");
div.appendChild(Table());
```

```css
#qqq {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="qqq"></div>
```

Comment: `appendChild` doesn't make a copy of the element you pass to it, so it will mutate the child if you mutate the element afterwards. Why do you need to set `innerHTML` to `""`?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the problem.  You are adding an element to a table, adding html to that element, and then clearing the html you just added, resulting in blank output.  This seems pretty straightforward

Comment: You add a `TR` without content `<td>content1</td><td>content2</td>`, result :  `the line can't be append.`

Comment: I want to clear **`table_row.innerHTML = ''`** to create a few more lines with different content. The algorithm is commented out below.

Comment: I want to clear the element and add another HTML code to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `table_row` variable contains a reference.  You will need to create a new element for each row.

```
// creates a DOM Element and saves a reference to it in the table_row variable
var table_row = document.createElement("tr");

// updates the DOM Element through the reference in the table_row variable
table_row.innerHTML += "<th>" + columns[i] + "</th>";

// still references the DOM Element, so you are clearing its content
// table_row.innerHTML = "";
```

You will need to . . .

```
// create a new DOM Element to use
table_row = document.createElement("tr");
// then update its contents
table_main_row.innerHTML += '<td></td>';
```

. . . for each iteration.

See [JavaScript on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) for tutorials, references, and more.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];
var rows = 5;

function createNewRow(headerRow)
{
    var newRowElem = null;

    try
    {
        newRowElem = document.createElement("tr");

        for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) 
        {
            if(headerRow) newRowElem.innerHTML += "<th>" + columns[i] + "</th>";
            else newRowElem.innerHTML += "<td>" + columns[i] + "</td>";
        }

    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("createNewRow Error" + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }

    return newRowElem;
}


function Table() 
{
    var table_layout = null;

    try
    {
        table_layout = document.createElement("table");

        // Create Header Row
        table_layout.appendChild(createNewRow(true));

        // Create Other Rows
        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        {
            table_layout.appendChild(createNewRow(false));
        }

    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("Table Error: " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }

    return table_layout;
}

</script>

<style>
#qqq {
  background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="qqq"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var div = document.getElementById("qqq");
    div.appendChild(Table());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would recommend calling a separate function for each row created.  I included a sample of such in this example.  Also, I moved your initial call to a script block just before the ending </body> element.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did so.

```js
var table_layout = document.createElement('table');
table_layout.setAttribute('id', 'main_table');
table_layout.setAttribute('border', '1');

var row = document.createElement('tr');
row.setAttribute('class', 'main_row');

for (var i = 0; i < this.fields.length; i++) { // строка с именами столбцов
 var th = document.createElement('th');
 th.setAttribute('class', 'cell_name');
 th.innerHTML = this.fields[i];
 row.appendChild(th);
}

table_layout.appendChild(row); //добавляем
row = document.createElement('tr'); // очищаем от старых элементов строку (переопределяем)
row.setAttribute('class', 'table_row');

var td = document.createElement('td');
 td.setAttribute('class', 'table_cell');
 // td.setAttribute('ondblclick', 'input_func()');
 td.addEventListener('click', function () {
  alert();
 });
 td.innerHTML='000';


for (var j = 0; j < this.fields.length; j++) { // создаем строку с N-количеством ячеек
 row.appendChild(td.cloneNode(true));
}

for (var i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) { // Добавляем её есколько раз через клона
 table_layout.appendChild(row.cloneNode(true));
}
```

But then redistribution with functions for the table.

```js
var table_layout = document.createElement('table');
table_layout.setAttribute('id', 'main_table');
table_layout.setAttribute('border', '1');

var row = table_layout.insertRow(0);
        var cell;

        for (var j = 0; j < this.fields.length; j++) { 
    cell = row.insertCell(j);
    cell.outerHTML = '<th>' + this.fields[j] + '</th>';
         cell.className = 'cell_name';
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) { 
   row = table_layout.insertRow(i + 1);
            row.className = 'row_table';

    for (var n = 0; n < this.fields.length; n++) { 
     cell = row.insertCell(n);
     // cell.innerHTML = '00';
          cell.className = 'table_cell';
          cell.innerHTML = '&nbsp';
         }
  }


  return table_layout;
```